# How can I place an anchor in ARKit relative to the ground with WorldAlignment rather than relative to the camera?

Tags: ios, arkit

I'm following along the SpriteKit example with ARKit and want to change the behavior such that instead of placing the sprite just in front of the camera - I want the sprite to always be at a fixed distance above the floor (plane?), e.g. eye-level.  I also want to use the WorldAlignment `gravityAndHeading` so that I can always place it in the same part of the room.

Here's the sample code

```
if let currentFrame = sceneView.session.currentFrame {

    // Create a transform with a translation of 1.5 meters in front of the camera
    var translation = matrix_identity_float4x4
    translation.columns.3.z = -1.5
    let transform = simd_mul(currentFrame.camera.transform, translation)

    // Add a new anchor to the session
    let anchor = ARAnchor(transform: transform)
    sceneView.session.add(anchor: anchor)
}
```

Do I need to get the camera's height position when I pass in the translation to `currentFrame.camera.transform`, or is there something that will give me the absolute or relative position vs 0?

Also, I'm assuming that I should turn on plane detection and add my anchor on plane detected? `configuration.planeDetection = .horizontal`

Comment: You'll have to make sure that at this point you've already detected an horizontal plane. You've no guarantee that such a plane would actually be the floor. Could be a table or anything else. You can probably chose the lowest one as the bottom. Then you can probably do something using plane.transform instead of camera.transform

Comment: I can't find any examples of a delegate method for plane detection using spritekit - the only examples I see use the scenekit delegate for plane detection.  What would the delegate method be for SpriteKit?  I see in the docs that say that an anchor gets added for the plane when plane detection is on - but I can't seem to find the method for it.

Comment: I'm just analyzing this myself, but my reading is that you don't need a plane for SpriteKit, just for SceneKit.  The transform you show should be performed relative to the camera's current position (including altitude), however, if you're in gravityAndHeading the z translation you're using would place the anchor 1.5 meters away on the North / South axis, not in front of you (to the North I think but not sure).  To change the height from the camera's position you'd translate the y coordinate, but I can't see a good way to get the position relative to the ground.